# ElevateZoom with slick slider issues

Tags: jquery, css, slick.js

I'm using slick slider with elevateZoom jquery plugin to show inner zoom. I have a small issue zoom container divs display zoom on hidden slides so user have no option to read to select options behind this. Here is screenshot for better explanation and [website link](http://lily-jean.com/product/singlet-top-jean/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just visited [your site](http://lily-jean.com/product/singlet-top-jean/), and it seems like the issue has been fixed somehow.

Anyway, I've just met this issue this morning when working on my project. After spending some hours trying various hacks that I found on the Internet, nothing really worked.

Finally, I came up with my own hack:

```css
// Here is the trick, written in LESS:
// In real code, this should be scoped further
//  to the slick instance that you want to apply this trick on.

.slick-slide {
 img {
    width: 0 !important;
    height: 0 !important;
    display: none !important;
  }
}

.slick-current, .slick-active {
  img {
    width: auto !important;
    height: auto !important;
    display: block !important;
  }
}
```

The basic idea is to have all slick slides that are inactive to have `display: none;`, so that a mouse hover over it doesn't activate the elevateZoom.

I don't really know why, when applying elevateZoom on slick then we can mouse over out-of-view slides - normally with a slick-only setup this issue doesn't occur.

The current active slick slide will have `display:block;` as normal, and everything works well.

[Here is the demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/veeVPR)